# Using poisson.test with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I want to run a Poisson test on every row of a tibble. However, mutate fails because poisson.test seems to be designed for numbers rather than columns. What is the best workaround? At the moment, the only thing I've managed to get working is an explicit for loop...

```
df <- tribble(
~count, ~time,
5, 10,
4, 7,
8, 10)

# Fails
df %>% mutate(rate = poisson.test(count, T = time)
# Error in poisson.test(remove_count, T = FHs) : 
#   the case k > 2 is unimplemented
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we want to apply on each row, one option is `map2` where it takes each element of 'count', 'time' and do the `poisson.test`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(rate = map2(count, time, poisson.test))
```

Or if we don't want to load another package (`purrr`), then this can be done with `rowwise`

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(rate = list(poisson.test(count, time)))
```

---

This will give the test output as a `list` column.  If we are interested in extracting the `estimate`

```
df %>%
   mutate(rate = map2_dbl(count, time, ~poisson.test(.x, .y)$estimate))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  count  time  rate
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5    10 0.5  
#2     4     7 0.571
#3     8    10 0.8
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple question. If I used `df2 = df %>%
   mutate(rate = map2(count, time, poisson.test))`, how would I then extract multiple elements from the list column (e.g. estimate and confidence interval)?

Comment: @yakzo You can do `df2 %>% mutate(est = map_dbl(rate, ~ .x$estimate), confL = map_dbl(rate, ~ .x$conf.int[1]), confU = map_dbl(rate, ~ .x$conf.int[2]))`